# codeigniter access config.php in database.php

Tags: php, codeigniter, configuration-files

At my work we have a typical setup

Develop on localhost
Test on staging
Live on production

We are using codeigniter.

Obviously it is a real pain having to change all the settings every time we move them around.

What I want to do is.

in config.php have `$config['env'] = 'localhost'; //'test'; //'production';`

Then in my `database.php` and `email.php`

```
$env = //config env variable

if($env === 'localhost'){
  //localhost settings
} elseif($env === 'test'){
  //staging settings
} elseif($env === 'production'){
  //production settings
}
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

In 1.7.x you can do this:

In database.php:

```
$CI = get_instance();
$active_group = $CI->config->item("active_group");
```

So that in config.php you can have:

```
$config['active_group'] = 'development'; // production, staging, etc
```